# "She kissed her son goodbye". Is there another better way?

Tags: sentence-construction

I don't understand the sentence "She kissed her son goodbye". It's not better to say "She kissed her son (in the) goodbye", isn't it?

Comment: *To kiss someone goodbye* is an idiom.  It simply means to give them a kiss as you bid them goodbye.

Comment: We can also kiss someone hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "in the" is decidedly worse, not better.  The original sentence is a perfectly natural, common idiom in English.

An expanded version that might help clarify the meaning for you would be:

*She kissed her son as a way of saying goodbye to him*